# How to use ANOVA (function = aov) for a fractional factorial designed experiment with 6 independent variables in R

Tags: r, anova

I have done an incomplete factorial design (fractional factorial design) experiment on different fertilizer applications.

Here is the format of the data:  [Excerpt of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdtjz.png)

I want to do an ANOVA in R using the function aov. I have 450 data points in total, 'Location' has 5 factors, N has 3, and F1,F2,F3+F4 have two each.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
ANOVA1<-aov(PlantWeight~Location*N*F1*F2*F3*F4, data = data)
summary(ANOVA1)
```

Independent variables F1,F2,F3+F4 are not applied in a factorial manner. Each sample either has F1,F2,F3+F4 or nothing applied. In the cases where no F1,F2,F3 or F4  fertiliser was applied the value 0 has been put in every column. This is the control to which each of F1,F2,F3+F4 will be compared to. If F1 has been applied then column F1 will read 1 and it will read NA in F2,F3+F4 columns.

When I try to run this ANOVA I get this error message:

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

Another approach I had was to but an 'x' instead of 'NA'. This has issues because it is assuming that x is a factor when it is not. It seemed to work fine except it would always ignore the F4.

```
ANOVA2<-aov(PlantWeight~((F1*Location*N)+(F2*Location*N)+(F3*Location*N)+
           (F4*Location*N)), data = data)
```

summary(ANOVA2)

Results:

```
                          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
F1                        2   10.3    5.13   5.742  0.00351 ** 
Location                  6  798.6  133.11 149.027  < 2e-16 ***
N                         2  579.6  289.82 324.485  < 2e-16 ***
F2                        1    0.3    0.33   0.364  0.54667    
F3                        1    0.4    0.44   0.489  0.48466    
F1:Location              10   26.5    2.65   2.962  0.00135 ** 
F1:N                      4    6.6    1.66   1.857  0.11737    
Location:N               10  113.5   11.35  12.707  < 2e-16 ***
Location:F2               5    6.5    1.30   1.461  0.20188    
N:F2                      2    2.7    1.37   1.537  0.21641    
Location:F3               5   33.6    6.72   7.529 9.73e-07 ***
N:F3                      2    2.5    1.23   1.375  0.25409    
F1:Location:N            20   12.4    0.62   0.696  0.83029    
F2:Location:N            10   18.9    1.89   2.113  0.02284 *  
F3:Location:N            10   26.8    2.68   3.001  0.00118 ** 
Residuals               359  320.6    0.89                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Any help on how to approach this would be wonderful!

Comment: Hi Scerfman, as per the error, one of your variables is a constant.

Comment: A couple of points: You are likely getting that error because F1 - F4 only have a single level (0). The rows with an `NA` value are being dropped by the model. You can check this by changing the data in a few rows so it will fit, and then using `nrow(ANOVA1$model)`. Right now the formula has all of your features as crossed. Based on what you said, I think what you are looking for is `PlantWeight ~ Location * N + F1 + F2 + F3 + F4`. Finally, could you combine F1 - F4 into a single feature (maybe call it F) with values of either none, F1, F2, F3, or F4 depending on treatment?

Comment: This is a really useful resource https://learnche.org/pid/design-analysis-experiments/fractional-factorial-designs/index also, include your data in the question rather than a link.  (Check out Kevin Dunn's work for code as to how to do it).